# Reactive Extensions: How to create a placeholder observable?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactive-extensions-js

I have a method, `getObs()`, that returns an observable, which should be shared by all callers. However, that observable might not exist when somebody calls `getObs()`, and creating it is an async operation, so my idea was to return a placeholder observable that is replaced with the real observable once it is created.

My basic attempt goes something like this:

```
var createSubject = new Rx.Subject();
var placeholder = createSubject.switchLatest();
```

Where I can return `placeholder` if the real observable does not exist when 'getObs()' is called. When the real observable is created, I use `createSubject.onNext(realObservable)`, which then passes it to `switchLatest()` that unwraps it for any subscribers.

However, it does seem like overkill to use a Subject and switchLatest for this purpose, so I am wondering if there is a more direct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the act of getting the observable itself is asynchronous, you should model that also as an observable.

For example...

```js
var getObsAsync = function () {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        var token = startSomeAsyncAction(function (result) {
                // the async action has completed!
                var obs = Rx.Observable.fromArray(result.dataArray);
                token = undefined;
                observer.OnNext(obs);
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }),
            unsubscribeAction = function () {
                if (asyncAction) {
                    stopSomeAsyncAction(token);
                }
            };            

        return unsubscribeAction;
    });
};

var getObs = function () { return getObsAsync().switchLatest(); };
```

And if you want to share a single instance of that observable, but you do not wish to get the observable *until* someone actually subscribes, then you do:

```js
// source must be a Connectable Observable (ie the result of Publish or Replay)
// will connect the observable the first time an observer subscribes
// If an action is supplied, then it will call the action with a disposable
// that can be used to disconnect the observable.
// idea taken from Rxx project
Rx.Observable.prototype.prime = function (action) {
    var source = this;
    if (!(source instanceof Rx.Observable) || !source.connect) {
        throw new Error("source must be a connectable observable");
    }

    var connection = undefined;
    return Rx.Observable.createWithDisposable(function (observer) {
        var subscription = source.subscribe(observer);

        if (!connection) {
            // this is the first observer.  Connect the underlying observable.
            connection = source.connect();
            if (action) {
                // Call action with a disposable that will disconnect and reset our state
                var disconnect = function() {
                    connection.dispose();
                    connection = undefined;
                };
                action(Rx.Disposable.create(disconnect));
            }
        }

        return subscription;
    });
};

var globalObs = Rx.Observable.defer(getObs).publish().prime();
```

Now code wherever can just use globalObs and not worry about it:

```js
// location 1
globalObs.subscribe(...);

// location 2
globalObs.select(...)...subscribe(...);
```

Notice, that no one actually even needs to call `getObs` because you just setup a global observable that will (via `defer`) call `getObs` for you when someone subscribes.

Comment: awesome answer as always. You really know your stuff. Can you explain the difference between `prime` and `refCount`?

Comment: `refCount` - keeps a count of the number of observers.  When count goes from 0 to 1, it connects to the source.  When count goes from 1 to 0, it disconnects.  So, if your observers come and go and your observable is `cold`, then if all of the observers unsubscribe, it sort of resets the observable so that the next observer will cause the cold observable to "start over".

Comment: `prime` - when count goes from 0 to 1, it connects to the source.  After that, it never disconnects even if all the observers unsubscribe.  The only way it would disconnect would be if you supplied a function argument to `prime()` so you could capture the disposable that represents the connection.  Then you could disconnect it whenever you wanted.

Comment: In the examples above, if you used `refCount`, then whenever all of the observers unsubscribed, the observable you received from your async method would be shutdown.  When a new observer finally subscribed, a new call to `getObs` would be made and a new observable started to be shared to the new observers.  That may actually be what you want.  I don't know.  Using `prime` would ensure only 1 call to `getObs` was ever made and events would just get "lost" if all the observers unsubscribed for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subject to hook up the source after the fact:

```
var placeholder = new Subject<YourType>();
// other code can now subscribe to placeholder, best expose it as IObservable
```

when the source is created:

```
var asyncCreatedObs = new ...;
placeholder.Subscribe(asyncCreatedObs);
// subscribers of placeholder start to see asyncCreatedObs
```

Comment: Oh, I see you are on JS... The code is for C#. Guess the syntax is a little different for JS, the concepts should be the same tho.